# C# CMD Install Printer

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to install a network printer on a non-domain machine.

I found the only way to prompt Windows Security to allow authentication to install the printer and run the exe on the shared drive to be by using `Start \\PAPERCUT\FollowMe` in CMD but when converting it to a C# winform, it does not install.

I am prompted to authenticate the connection to the server and the exe runs, but the printer does not install and does not throw any errors.

```
Ping pingSender = new Ping();
    IPAddress address = IPAddress.Loopback;
    PingReply reply = pingSender.Send("192.168.137.37");

    if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
        startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        startInfo.Arguments = @"/C Start \\PAPERCUT\FollowMe";
        startInfo.Arguments = @"/C rundll32 printui.dll PrintUIEntry /in /n \\PAPERCUT\FollowMe";
        startInfo.Arguments = @"/C rundll32 printui.dll PrintUIEntry /y /n \\PAPERCUT\FollowMe";
        startInfo.Arguments = @"/C Start \\PAPERCUT\PCClient\win\pc-client.exe";
        process.StartInfo = startInfo;
        process.Start();

        greenConnectionLabel.Visible = true;
        redConnectionLabel.Visible = false;
    }
    else
    {
        greenConnectionLabel.Visible = false;
        redConnectionLabel.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why you are starting `cmd.exe` and not directly `rundll32.exe`? Also I am not sure that you can run one `cmd.exe` with multiple `/C <app>` arguments.

Comment: I didn't realise I could do that, however it does not change the result. @i486

Comment: Why are you using rundll32 *at all*? Why don't you use the Win32 API or WMI directly to install the printer?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos `rundll32` and `printui.dll` is good method. It is shorter than pinvoke of Win32 (in case his program is in C#).

Comment: Do you have admin rights (UAC)?

Comment: Executing an external process is *not* a good method, when the functionality is fully available trhough APIs and even through Powershell. WMI exists precisely for such administrative tasks, both for the local and remote machines

Comment: .NET already contains printer management functions. You can use  [PrintServer.IstallPrintQueue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms552946(v=vs.110).aspx) to install a network printer and provide parameters. The same functionality is also available through PowerShell with the `add-printer` command

Comment: You should also try [LocalPrintServer.ConnectToPrintQueue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms552872(v=vs.110).aspx) to connect to a network printer by passing the UNC path